# Change QwtPlot background while using dark mode gui?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator, qwt

When I dissable dark mode which is provided via BreezeStyleSheet:

https://github.com/Alexhuszagh/BreezeStyleSheets

it works (I can change background with set canvas palette to whatever I want and then attach it to QwtPlot). But when I use style sheet it seems almost impossible to set it. Have anybody some ideas how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom widget based on QwtPlot it will be:

```
this->canvas()->setStyleSheet("background-color: black;border: none;");
```

in constructor.